# Roman page numbering for abstracts in report class problem

Tags: page-numbering, abstract, report, front-matter

I am writing a document with class `report`. I want that the first pages i.e. Declaration, Abstract, Acknowledgements, Table of Contents, List of Figures and List of Tables have page numbering roman, and the main content has arabic page numbers.

I am using this command to override the `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands provided for the book class.

```
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother
```

This works for table of contents, list of figures and list of tables. however since abstract, acknowledgments and declaration are all defined with the following:

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Name of this section}
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}
```

no page numbers are being displayed on these pages. I tried using `\thispagestyle{plain}` in these sections, but this caused each page to be numbered as i. and the counting from i. onwards start from toc.

How can I start roman page numbering from the declaration onwards instead?

Comment: Please always post a complete small document that shows the problem. report class has two definitions of abstract depending on whether titlepage is in use, and it depends where you have put `\frontmatter` relative to `abstract`.

Answer (score 1):

You can redifine the abstract:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newenvironment{multipleabstract}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\abstractname}{#1}\begin{abstract}\thispagestyle{plain}}
  {\end{abstract}}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \section*{\abstractname}%
  \else
    \small
    \begin{center}%
      {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
  \fi}
  {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multipleabstract}{Abstract1}
  ...
\end{multipleabstract}

\newpage

\begin{multipleabstract}{Abstract2}
  ...
\end{multipleabstract}

\end{document}
```